# Anybody have issue some times Total showing double?

Tags: magento-1.9, totals

This is not duplicate question.

Actually i see there are some user they have this issue when create new total or add some module related to total. because they don't use condition to check total for only shipping.

But in my case i check in table `sales_flat_quote_address` and i found there is 2 entry for shipping address and 1 for billing for quote id which have double total.

**Note :** I am getting this problem sometimes not every order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have still not found why some time there are 2 shipping address in `sales_flat_quote_address` table. but I used Quick fix to resolved problem temporary still i am looking for reason why there is double address . May be this solution can help someone.

Please make sure don't change in core file this just for reference you need to rewrite this class to add code:
Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php

in the init() function after line: `$this->getQuote()->setCheckoutMethod('');` 
Add below code.

`$addresses = $this->getQuote()->getAllAddresses();

if (count($addresses) > 2) {
  for($i = 2; $i < count($addresses); $i++) {
    $address = $addresses[$i];
    $address->isDeleted(true);
  }
}`

Above code will remove 1 address if there will be double entry when you goto cart page.